# Undefined constant Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, crud, scaffold, ruby-on-rails-4

by copying and trying to modify a scaffold manually in Rails 4, I got an error when I want to delete an article: `uninitialized constant Article::Tag`.
Another error when I want to edit an Article: "undefined local variable or method `article_params'".

I don't know from where it can comes from, the highlited error which are displayed are `@article.destroy`  and if `@article.update(article_params)`. I don't understand at all considering I think having copied perfectely the scaffold...

```
def destroy
  @article.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end


def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.update(article_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Thansk you for your help

Comment: The problem is in your Article model, I believe

Comment: Thanks, It was the solution, I haven't think about the model at all! 

The destroy wasn't working because of the "has_and_belongs_to_many"
And the editing problem wasn't working because of the "validates_presence_of"